# What might explain the 2 butterfly images in the picture?

Tags: mobile

[image]This picture of a butterfly was taken using a mobile phone camera. Attached image is unedited. I am looking for explanations for the dual image of the butterfly

Comment: Pure speculation: your camera take two photos to handle high contrast situation. But because of the time between two photos butterfly more. And merging algorithm do not handle well moving object. So you see kind of ghost butterfly.

Comment: Agree with Romeo. Probably some HDR setting - the camera actually takes 2 exposures in quick succession, using different exposure settings, then merges them into 1 image. If you check the documentation from the phone manufacturer, it may well say to avoid moving subjects.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, very helpful